# Using slots in class for declaring a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, oop, slot

I have a class that takes a dict and initialize constructors to set the class members. I am new to Python Object Oriented and I read about `__slots__` attributes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472000/usage-of-slots) and am wondering if I need to declare `__slots__` for my sample class below? If not, what is the best and most pythonic way here?

```
class MyClass:
    __slots__: List[str] = ["tmp_dict"]
    def __init__(self, tmp_dict):
        self.tmp_dict = tmp_dict
```

Comment: `__slots__` is purely a technique for reducing the memory footprint of your objects.  It's not something you should normally bother with unless you expect millions of instances of your class to exist simultaneously.

Comment: you dont need to declare `__slots__` for your class. "Pythonic" on its own does not really mean anything, to quote someone: No single word has done as much damage to the Python ecosystem as “Pythonic.” It’s the ultimate tool to discredit any kind of work based on knee jerk reactions with no recourse because it’s 100% subjective.